# Laravel error in /bootstrap/start.php on line 60 \Illuminate\Foundation\start.php no such file

Tags: php, laravel, github

So i am trying to open this github project I found through cmd by typing "php artisan serve" but the output is error.

Output:

```
PHP Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\qarans/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\qarans\bootstrap\start.php on line 60

Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\qarans/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\qarans\bootstrap\start.php on line 60

PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\qarans/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\qarans\bootstrap\start.php on line 60

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\qarans/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\qarans\bootstrap\start.php on line 60
```

**So i looked through the bootstrap/start.php file on line 60, there is this code**

```
$framework = $app['path.base'] .
'/vendor/laravel/framework/src';

require $framework . '/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Return The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This script returns the application instance. The instance is given to
| the calling script so we can separate the building of the instances
| from the actual running of the application and sending responses.
|
 */

return $app;
```

I tried using the `composer install`, `composer update`, `php artisan optimize` and others that I found but the output is still the same. I wonder if I should type something in my **composer.json** file in the "require" section but I don't know what to insert. I'm quite new to this github and laravel thing.

```
"require": {
        "laravel/framework": "^5.8.0",
        "sastrawi/sentence-detector": "~1",
        "sastrawi/tokenizer": "0.*",
        "sastrawi/sastrawi": "~1",
        "rcrowe/twigbridge": "0.5.*",
        "laraiba/resource": "dev-master",
        "patchwork/utf8": "1.1.*",
    },
```

Comment: The error is clear, the file could not be found. Please check that file is really where you expect to be. Start checking what do you receive on `$framework . '/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php';`

Comment: delete the composer.lock.json file and vendor folder and re-run the "composer install". OR run "composer dump-autoload" command

Comment: I tried the `composer dump-autoload` then `composer install` but the output is still same. I'm sorry but I don't really understand what you mean by check that file is really where you expect to be. I went through the 'C:\xampp\htdocs\qarans/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php' file to check but there is a lot of files inside the foundation files, and I'm quite confused on what to look at.

Comment: is your vendor folder exist?

Comment: if it is not exist then delete composer.lock file and go to your terminal and type compser install